# jQuery slideshow: how do I modify this code to show a custom pager per slide?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, pager

Right now the code is spitting out 1 pager item per slide existing. I'm trying to get it to show a custom pager graphic per slide. IE: slide 1 shows pager1.gif, slide 2 shows pager2.gif, etc. Thanks!

```
   appendControlls: function()
{ 

 if (options.slideControlls == 'items')
 { 
  var elementToAppend = options.appendControlls || slideWrapper[0];
  controlls = $('<div></div>').addClass('slidecontrolls').insertAfter(elementToAppend);

  slides.each(function(i)
  { 
   var controller = $('<a href="#" class="ie6fix '+current_class+'"></a>').appendTo(controlls);
   controller.bind('click', {currentSlideNumber: i}, slideWrapper.methods.switchSlide);
   current_class = "";
  }); 

  controlls.width(controlls.width()).css('float','none');
 }
 return this;

},
```

Comment: I solved my own problem a few hours after asking - I simply added        "slide'+i+'" to the loop ( .appendTo(controlls) ); This spit out a custom css bit I could model in css.

Answer (score 0):

Call me lazy, but I quit making my own slideshows after I found this:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It's about as simplified as possible and allows you to customize and recreate it into about any slider scenario you can think of.